# PostGIS query to retrieve the largest polygon for multi-polygons by grouping on attribute field

Tags: postgis, postgresql, natural-earth

I'm working with the Natural Earth 10m Admin 1 States Provinces polygon data. This dataset contains multi-polygons for each state / province in the entire world. What I'd like to do is to grab the largest polygon for each state / province, then create a centroid that is inside that polygon for labeling purposes in web cartography.

I went ahead and calculated the area for each polygon using `ST_Area(geom::geography)` for the dataset and so far my PostGIS query looks like this, which returns the the largest polygon for a single state /province:

```
SELECT area, name, ST_Centroid(geom) geom
FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces
WHERE area IN (
      SELECT area
      FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces 
      WHERE name = 'state province name' 
      ORDER BY area DESC
      LIMIT 1
)
```

However I'm unsure of how to determine the best way to iterate over all features in the dataset to grab the polygon for each state / province with the largest area. Would the best way to do this be to create a function in PGSQL? Or is there a simpler way via plain old SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to one-step it, using the `ST_Dump` function to get the subcomponents...

```
WITH geoms AS (
    SELECT name, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom AS geom 
    FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom
FROM geoms
ORDER BY name ASC, ST_Area(geom) DESC;
```

The dump strips out the individual components. The order by sets up the relation in a good order so that the distinct on can pick off the first entry of each category (name) we care about.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do everything in a single PostGIS query.

First, you need to create a query that splits the multi-polygons into simple polygons. This can be done with something like:

```
SELECT gid,
    ST_GeometryN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(geom))) AS geom
FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces;
```

where `gid` is a unique identifier (primary key or other unique field).

Then you can calculate the area for all simple polygons, and keep only the biggest one with something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (gid) A.*, ST_Area(geom) area FROM 
    (SELECT gid,
        ST_GeometryN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(geom))) AS geom
     FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces) A
ORDER BY gid, area desc;
```

with the previous query from before as subquery.

Finally, you only need to calculate the centroid on each of them, which can again be done using a subquery:

```
SELECT gid, ST_Centroid(geom) AS centroid FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (gid) A.*, ST_Area(geom) area FROM 
    (SELECT gid,
        ST_GeometryN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(geom))) AS geom
     FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces) A
ORDER BY gid, area desc) B;
```