# Dissolve polygons based on max attribute value and retain attributes for that feature?

Tags: qgis, postgis, dissolve

I want to dissolve a layer containing 9 features and have remaining in the attribute table only the attributes associated with max area feature.

I have tried several dissolve tools within QGIS but none seem to allow this.

In the example I wish to dissolve the features into one and only have the max area (at top) associated with the layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all 9 features
2. Toggle the *Edit* icon
3. Click the **Merge Selected Features** tool:

   [image: Merge selected features]
4. Select the attributes you want to remain at the end:

   [image: Merge attributes]
5. Click *OK* and your features should be merged with the values you selected.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the process across a large dataset without having to manually enter 'feature 9' into each field?

Comment: @ColinMcGuane - I'm sure you can with PostGIS (which you tagged) but I'm not very familiar with this yet...

Comment: A work around by @PaulRamsey

http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162165/84182

Comment: @ColinMcGuane - Good catch! Hope that workaround works for you ;)